# Failed GLX request when running python OpenGL demo

Tags: python, opengl

I am testing a python OpenGL [demo](http://pg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#complete-example):

```
import pg

class Window(pg.Window):
    def setup(self):
        self.wasd = pg.WASD(self)
        self.wasd.look_at((0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 0))
        self.program = pg.DirectionalLightProgram()
        self.context = pg.Context(self.program)
        sphere = pg.Sphere(3, 0.5, (0, 0, 0))
        self.context.position = pg.VertexBuffer(sphere.positions)
        self.context.normal = pg.VertexBuffer(sphere.normals)
    def update(self, t, dt):
        matrix = self.wasd.get_matrix()
        matrix = matrix.perspective(65, self.aspect, 0.1, 100)
        self.context.matrix = matrix
        self.context.camera_position = self.wasd.position
    def draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.context.draw(pg.GL_TRIANGLES)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pg.run(Window)
```

And it crashed with the error:

```
 X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  168 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  114
  Current serial number in output stream:  114
```

My `glxgears` works fine and `glxinfo` shows

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: No (If you want to find out why, try setting LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose)
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
...
```

I've set `export LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose` and it still shows the same result. I don't know if direct rendering being set to 'No' caused the error to happen. Could anyone give a hint?

Comment: The output of glxinfo you added show the version of the glx implementation, not the supported OpenGL version. There has to be a line starting with something like `OpenGL version string:...`. Which version do you require to start your demo?

Comment: Your `glxinfo` output reports that it can not create a direct rendering context. Unless you're using a networked X11 session (SSH forward or XDMCP remote X11) that isn't supposed to happen. If that happens when running `glxinfo` on the very same machine your monitor is connected to, then you have a strong indicator that you don't have the graphics drivers properly installed.

Comment: @BDL `glxinfo` also gives `OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 10.1.3)`, I've updated the link to the demo. I am not sure the required version of OpenGL for this demo.

Comment: @datenwolf I am on the very monitor connected to. I might get my driver updated/replaced.

Comment: I saw at least one shader with version 120 on their github, so OpenGL 2.1 will be required.